# How to parse CSV and import to MYSQL issue

Tags: mysql, excel, csv, phpmyadmin

I am really stuck at this moment.. I searched and researched and I did not find anything similar, so maybe what I want is not doable.

I have a .xls file in this format

```
|contact| col1  |col2  |  col3  |
---------------------------------
|name1   | info1 |info2 | info3  |
|address1|       |      |        |
|phone1  |       |      |        |
|        |       |      |        |
|name2   |       |      |        | 
|address2| info1 |info2 | info3  |
|phone2  |       |      |        |
|        |       |      |        | 
|name_n  | info1 | info2| info3  |
|addres_n|       |      |        |
|phone_n |       |      |        |
----------------------------------
```

So I was thinking about creating a table which will be called contact, and another called info. The table contact will contain id(primary key),name,address and phone as fields. And another table with id (primary key) , name (foreign key), col1,col2 and col3. In such a way that if I want to know the details of the name (in table info ) I could go to the other table and see all the values.

So I researched about how to import this xls format file and the optimal solution will be convert  the xls file to a csv file delimited by comma.

Therefore, the code which I was thinking to use is (after converting to csv- delimited by comma) the following:

But the point is that I just want to to the following:

- "Info" Table :    name1,info1,info2,info3.
- "Contact" Table : name1,address,phone1.

**Related to "Info" Table**

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/username/myfile.csv' 
INTO TABLE numbers FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
LINES STARTING BY '-' TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(contact,col1,col2,col3);
```

It is ok when I'm filling the table because I just have to add a '-' at the beginning of the row which I want to fill into the table (the row which contains a non-empty field.)

**Related to "Contact" table:**

It is being difficult since, if I want to take just the column of contact I will have to add some symbol and then operate. Well, I was thinking in add an '*' (for instance) at the beggining of name1 and another one at the end of phone1 for defining the boundaries of the LINE. But I want to define also the fields, which will be a ';' as well. However, the algorithm of LOAD DATA INFILE takes the empty fields also. And I just want to take the fields which contains something different than "empty string"/"null"/. So the question is if I would be able to say something to avoid the empty string. Because as a I read in the [MySQL DOC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) this is written:

> An empty field value is interpreted different from a missing field:
>
> For string types, the column is set to the empty string.
>
> For numeric types, the column is set to 0.
>
> For date and time types, the column is set to the appropriate “zero” value for >the type. See Section 11.3, “Date and Time Types”.

But it does not say anything about avoid it. (I mean, If is an empty value, then pass the the next field and evaluate again until find a non-empty value)

I am asking that because with my idea of face it It will fill a row like that :
Name1,null,null,null,address1,null,null,null,phone1 and so on.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are name1,address1,phone1** 3 rows in your excel sheet?

Comment: no, just the values of that.

 This : |contact| col1  |col2  |  col3 |  is what I have in my excel spreedsheet. which is avoided with "IGNORE 1 LINES"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

focusing just on Contact for now, what if your excel spreadsheet has 4 columns where `columnA` is action with `N` for all rows. You change it to `Y` if you want it ultimately in your **real table**.

Your csv now has 4 columns:

action, Name, address, phone

You `load data infile` into a **worktable**. Now you have your data in (some not actually wanted), and an `insert into select` where action='y' will finish it up, into your **real table** from **worktable**.

Comment: Ok I think that I got your Idea. So firstly I could do what i thought.. but firstly I import the csv with the "null"  values into the "Draft Table" and then I operate there in order to take ( with "insert into select" ) the non-empty values to the real table.

I think that this option is the most doable one among the other replies. 
Thanks :=)

Answer (score 0):

In Excel you can create two worksheets, the first with contact data, the second with info data. Those sheets can be separately exported as csv files.

Comment: I know but I have like 70 woorksheets with |contact col1 col2 col3|.. therefore I can do it by hand of course... but I think that is not so efficient.. maybe now is ok because I only have 70 worksheets but imagine that I have 5000000000 worksheets.. is not efficient at all.